# Distinguish empty string and null value on COPY command

Tags: postgresql

I have the following command that reads and insert from stdin in a SQL file:

```
COPY test_table (id, col1, col2) FROM stdin DELIMITER ',' ;
1, "",,
2, "",,
```

as above the col1 values should be treated as empty string but instead I get an error:

```
null value in column "col1" violates not null constraint
```

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statement so that I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

three **,** (comma) actually you are inserting 4 fields/columns!

You can try

```
COPY test_table (id, col1, col2) FROM stdin  with (format csv, force_not_null(col1), DELIMITER ',') ;
1,"",
2,"",
\.
```

or

```
COPY test_table (id, col1, col2) FROM stdin  with (format csv, force_not_null(col1,col2), DELIMITER ',') ;
3,"",
4,"",
\.
```

Both query will make col1 value as  empty string. But the first one will make col2 value to null, the second query will make col2 value as empty string.

Comment: But that would cause a different error...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you be more specific. I am sorry. I didn't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I was too terse. You are right that there is a comma too much, but that should result in `ERROR:  extra data after last expected column`. So the example in the question is not correct or incomplete.